# How to use keylistener in different thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to have input operations in different thread, what should i write into run method? Or may be it is a better way to do this?

```
public class Player implements Runnable, KeyListener{

    int speed;

    public Player() 
    {
        speed = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {       
        //what should i write here?
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        startMove(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        endMove(e);
    }   


       public void startMove(KeyEvent e)
    {        
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        switch (key) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                speed = 2;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                speed = -2;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void endMove(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
            speed = 0; 
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
            speed = 0;

    }   
}
```

This code should detect key events and then depends on key code call startMove() or endMove() functions. And that all should be in the same thread. Should i use while loop into run and then somehow put there functions?

Comment: You should use a `Timer` instead of a thread unless there's some reason not to. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: @Radiodef, but then it will be in the main thread, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your design is "upside" down.

First of all, UI events **always** come down to you in the [AWT event dispatcher thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

And what your code is doing: changing the speed of for some Player object. Where is there a need for *another* thread?

Meaning: you should already use some other "game controller thread". The code run in that thread simply **checks** the value of that `speed` field; and makes use of that.

The core thing is: your start/end methods just change a field; and that is fine. And you should keep it that way. And have *other* code outside of that class "do its thing" based on the speed changed by those mouse events.